# CS50 pset4 filter "blur

Tags: c, filter, blur, cs50

So I have this problem in pset4 filter less comfortable. My blur somehow don't work. My problem is it seems that it doesnt loop for height so the only thing that works in my code is the first row.

My code works fine for the first row but theres no changes in second row and so on. Its like theres a breaks function in my code so that it will stop after the first row. I thought it was my condition in if() and maybe I was confused in the condition but it doesnt explain why it dont work for the lower left and right corner of the box, the condition are so simple so theres no confusion. I mean lets assumed my condition in the edges and middle part of the pixel is wrong but it should still calculate the corner of the last row of the box. Even if theres something wrong with my condition or formula, it should change the value of the RGB pixel but it doesnt.

:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image

testing with sample 3x3 image

```
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)

second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)

third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
```

Expected Output:

```
70 85 95

80 95 105


90 105 115

117 130 140

127 140 149

137 150 159

163 178 188

170 185 194

178 193 201
```

Actual Output:

```
70 85 95

80 95 105

90 105 115

110 130 140

120 140 150

130 150 160

200 210 220

220 230 240

240 250 255
```

Here's the code

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
// Copying the height and width length
int heilen = height;
int widlen = width;


int avgRed;
int avgGreen;
int avgBlue;

// Creating temporary array
int tmpR[height][width];
int tmpG[height][width];
int tmpB[height][width];

//storing the values of the image[i][j] to my temporary array
for (int i = 0; i < heilen; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < widlen; j++)
    {
        // storing the current images arrays to tmpRGB
        tmpR[i][j] = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        tmpG[i][j] = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        tmpB[i][j] = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
    }
}


for (height = 0; height < heilen; height++)
{
    for (width = 0; width < widlen; width++)
    {
        //=================== PIXELS IN CORNERS
        //upper left corner side of the box
        if (height == 0 && width == 0)
        {
            //calculating the total values of the curreent row and pixel and current row and pixel + 1
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width + 1];

            //calculating the total values of the next row current pixel and pixel + 1
            float after_row_Red = tmpR[height + 1][width] + tmpR[height + 1][width + 1];

            //getting the average of the total current row and next row and dividing it to 4
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + after_row_Red) / 4);


            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width + 1];
            float after_row_Green = tmpG[height + 1][width] + tmpG[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + after_row_Green) / 4);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width + 1];
            float after_row_Blue = tmpB[height + 1][width] + tmpB[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + after_row_Blue) / 4);

        }

        // upper right corner side of Box
        else if (height == 0 && width == widlen - 1)
        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width - 1];
            float after_row_Red = tmpR[height + 1][width] + tmpR[height + 1][width - 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + after_row_Red) / 4);


            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width - 1];
            float after_row_Green = tmpG[height + 1][width] + tmpG[height  + 1][width - 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + after_row_Green) / 4);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width - 1];
            float after_row_Blue = tmpB[height + 1][width] + tmpB[height + 1][width - 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + after_row_Blue) / 4);

        }

        //lower left corner side of the box
        else if (height == heilen - 1 && width == 0)
        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Red =  tmpR[height - 1][width] + tmpR[height - 1][width + 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + before_row_Red) / 4);

            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Green =  tmpG[height - 1][width] + tmpG[height - 1][width + 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + before_row_Green) / 4);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Blue =  tmpB[height - 1][width] + tmpB[height - 1][width + 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + before_row_Blue) / 4);
        }

        //lower right corner side of the box
        else if (height == heilen - 1 && width == widlen - 1)
        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width - 1];
            float before_row_Red =  tmpR[height - 1][width] + tmpR[height - 1][width - 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + before_row_Red) / 4);

            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width - 1];
            float before_row_Green =  tmpG[height - 1][width] + tmpG[height - 1][width - 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + before_row_Green) / 4);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width - 1];
            float before_row_Blue =  tmpB[height - 1][width] + tmpB[height - 1][width - 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + before_row_Blue) / 4);
        }


        // ===================== PIXELS ON EDGES

        //upper side of the box
        else if ( (height == 0 && width >= 1) && (height == 0 &&width < widlen - 1) )
        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width - 1] + tmpR[height][width + 1];
            float after_row_Red = tmpR[height + 1][width] + tmpR[height + 1][width - 1] + tmpR[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + after_row_Red) / 6);

            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width - 1] + tmpG[height][width + 1];
            float after_row_Green = tmpG[height + 1][width] + tmpG[height + 1][width - 1] + tmpG[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + after_row_Green) / 6);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width - 1] + tmpB[height][width + 1];
            float after_row_Blue = tmpB[height + 1][width] + tmpB[height + 1][width - 1] + tmpB[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + after_row_Blue) / 6);
        }

        //lower side of the box
        else if (  ( height == heilen - 1 && width >= 1) && ( height == heilen - 1 && width < widlen - 1) )

        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width - 1] + tmpR[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Red =  tmpR[height - 1][width] + tmpR[height - 1][width - 1] + tmpR[height - 1][width + 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + before_row_Red) / 6);

            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width - 1] + tmpG[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Green =  tmpG[height - 1][width] + tmpG[height - 1][width - 1] + tmpG[height - 1][width + 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + before_row_Green) / 6);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width - 1] + tmpB[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Blue =  tmpB[height - 1][width] + tmpB[height - 1][width - 1] + tmpB[height - 1][width + 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + before_row_Blue) / 6);
        }

        // left side of the box
        else if (  (height >= 1 && width == 0) && (height < heilen - 1 && width == 0) )
        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Red =  tmpR[height - 1][width] + tmpR[height - 1][width + 1];
            float after_row_Red = tmpR[height + 1][width] + tmpR[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + before_row_Red + after_row_Red) / 6);

            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Green =  tmpG[height - 1][width] + tmpG[height - 1][width + 1];
            float after_row_Green = tmpG[height + 1][width] + tmpG[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + before_row_Green + after_row_Green) / 6);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Blue =  tmpB[height - 1][width] + tmpB[height - 1][width + 1];
            float after_row_Blue = tmpB[height + 1][width] + tmpB[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + before_row_Blue + after_row_Blue) / 6);

        }

        //right side of the box
        else if ( ( height >= 1 && width == widlen- 1) && (height <= heilen -1 && width == widlen - 1) )
        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width - 1];
            float before_row_Red =  tmpR[height - 1][width] + tmpR[height - 1][width - 1];
            float after_row_Red = tmpR[height + 1][width] + tmpR[height + 1][width - 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + before_row_Red + after_row_Red) / 6);

            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width - 1];
            float before_row_Green =  tmpG[height - 1][width] + tmpG[height - 1][width - 1];
            float after_row_Green = tmpG[height + 1][width] + tmpG[height + 1][width - 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + before_row_Green + after_row_Green) / 6);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width - 1];
            float before_row_Blue =  tmpB[height - 1][width] + tmpB[height - 1][width - 1];
            float after_row_Blue = tmpB[height + 1][width] + tmpB[height + 1][width - 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + before_row_Blue + after_row_Blue) / 6);

        }


        //====================MIDDLE PIXELS

        //middle of the box
        else if ( (height >= 1 && width >= 1) && (height < heilen - 1 && width < widlen - 1) )
        {
            float current_row_Red = tmpR[height][width] + tmpR[height][width - 1] + tmpR[height][width + 1];
            float after_row_Red = tmpR[height + 1][width] + tmpR[height + 1][width - 1] + tmpR[height + 1][width + 1];
            float before_row_Red =  tmpR[height - 1][width] + tmpR[height - 1][width - 1] + tmpR[height - 1][width + 1];
            avgRed = round ((current_row_Red + before_row_Red + after_row_Red) / 9);

            float current_row_Green = tmpG[height][width] + tmpG[height][width - 1] + tmpG[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Green =  tmpG[height - 1][width] + tmpG[height - 1][width - 1] + tmpG[height - 1][width + 1];
            float after_row_Green = tmpG[height + 1][width] + tmpG[height + 1][width - 1] + tmpG[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgGreen = round ((current_row_Green + before_row_Green + after_row_Green) / 9);

            float current_row_Blue = tmpB[height][width] + tmpB[height][width - 1] + tmpB[height][width + 1];
            float before_row_Blue =  tmpB[height - 1][width] + tmpB[height - 1][width - 1] + tmpB[height - 1][width + 1];
            float after_row_Blue = tmpB[height + 1][width] + tmpB[height + 1][width - 1] + tmpB[height + 1][width + 1];
            avgBlue = round ((current_row_Blue + before_row_Blue + after_row_Blue) / 9);

        }

        //Assigning the cuurent average of RGB to image[][]
        image[height][width].rgbtRed = avgRed;
        image[height][width].rgbtGreen = avgGreen;
        image[height][width].rgbtBlue = avgBlue;


    }
    return;
}
```

}

You will notice that starting from the second row the actual output value is the same as the given value.

I know its not the most efficient way to do it but I can't help it, Im still beginner, just started coding for more than 1 month. Please help me >_<

Comment: Basically it only loop once in the first for-loop.

Comment: Remove the `return` statement near the bottom. Then the outer loop will run to completion.

Comment: OMG! thank you very much!!! Ive been trying to fix this for like the whole afternoon,

Comment: Damn, yeah all works fine. ahhhhhhhhh.

Comment: this stupid mistake. Like more than 4 hours just because I missed the return that I did not even wrote.

Comment: In general, stepping through the code in a debugger sometimes highlights problems that evade an initial inspection of the code.

Comment: Not an immediate concern but worth reading up on variable storage. `tmpR`, `tmpG` and `tmpB` are going to be placed on the stack. If you start dealing with large images it will use lots of space on the stack and there's no opportunity to deal with memory allocation failures, cf `malloc` and heap storage.